# Convert string input to integer

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, int, converters

I can't convert a string to an integer correctly with the code below.

I take `lang` input as a string. I want to accept any input, because if I restrict the input to integers, then any letter entered by the user will cause an error.

This code:

```
lang=[]
def chooseLang():
    global lang
    while lang !='1' and lang != '2':
        print ('Select (1 or 2):')
        lang=input()
    return lang

def convertStr(lang):
    ret=int(lang)
    return ret   
#-----------------------Program-----------------------
chooseLang()
convertStr(lang)

c=2+lang
print (c)
```

... causes this error:

```
in <module> c=2+lang
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Trying do everything in one function has the same effect:

```
lang=[]    
def chooseLang():
    global lang
    while lang !='1' and lang != '2':
        print ('Select (1 or 2):')
        lang=input()
    return lang
    ret=int(lang)

chooseLang()
c=2+lang
print (c)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you start out with `lang` as an empty list? Why do you make it a global? How can calling `int()` possibly give an error after you check if the string is `"1"` or `"2"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use the returned value from convertStr() function in the first example:

```
lang = convertStr(lang)
```

In your second example `ret = int(lang)` is unreachable due to `return lang` before it.

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/KmqNRg)

```
def choose_lang():
    lang = None # NOTE: this `lang` has nothing to do with the global `lang`
    while True: 
        try:
            lang = int(input("select (1 or 2)"))
        except ValueError:
            pass
        if lang not in [1, 2]:
            print("\ntry again")
        else:
            break
    return lang

lang = choose_lang()
c = 2 + lang
print(c)
```

Comment: Good alternative, thx for this method!